# What traits or methods are implemented for fn items?

Tags: function, rust, traits

I'm trying to find out what things I can do with a fn item. I could find something for fn pointer in std lib source, but nothing about fn item.

I know about `Copy`, `Fn`, being called and somehow being casted to fn pointer (but not sure if by trait or by built-in compiler magic). Is there anything else?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you areasking about. Are you interested in the differences between the function item type of an individual function and the corresponding function pointer type? The latter is not a reference, and since your question mentions "fn references" multiple times, I'm not sure this is what you mean.

Comment: For what it's worth, function items can only be called and copied, but they coerce function pointers in many situations; the details of the latter coercion are not fully documented.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I interpret the question like: for whatever type, there is a documentation page that shows the implemented traits; where is this page for `fn`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm aware of subtle difference between fn item and fn reference. I want to know what can be done with fn item without coercing it to fn reference. Copying and calling, that's fair, thank you.

Comment: @CodeSandwich My confusion comes only from your choice of words – "fn reference". You seem to use this term for a _function pointer_, but it wasn't at all clear that this is what you meant, since a function pointer is not a reference in the usual Rust sense of the word.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios There is a documentation page for [function pointer types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html), but none for function item types. I don't think that link is helpful for this question.

Comment: Why hasn't this question received an answer as `fn items` really don't have a documentation page that I could find explicitly stating the traits they have implemented on them.